# Bullets not going towards the center of the screen

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

So, I'm trying to make a 3D shooter and I'm facing a problem where the bullets are not going towards the center of the screen. They're depending on the BulletEffect position.

```
    void Shoot()
    {
        BulletEffect.Play();
        Bun.Play("RifleShoot");
        Src.PlayOneShot(Clip);

        GameObject Bullet2 = Instantiate(Bullet, BulletEffect.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        Vector3 direction = GetDirectionToCenter();
        Rigidbody BulletRb = Bullet2.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        BulletRb.velocity = direction * BulletSpeed;

        /*RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(Cam.transform.position, Cam.transform.forward, out hit, Range, Layer))
        {
            Debug.Log(hit.transform.name);

            hit.transform.GetComponent<EnemyScript>().TakeDamage(Damage);
        }
        */
    }

    Vector3 GetDirectionToCenter()
    {
            // Get the center of the screen in screen coordinates
        Vector3 screenCenter = new Vector3(Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 2, 0);

        // Convert the screen point to a world point
        Vector3 worldCenter = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenCenter);

        // Calculate the direction from the firePoint to the center of the screen
        Vector3 direction = (worldCenter - BulletEffect.transform.position).normalized;

        return new Vector3(direction.x, direction.y, 0f);
    }
```

I tried everything but cant seem to solve it

Comment: does it head the opposite way, what happens?

Comment: yeah, but if i rotate the bullet effect (bullet spawn) the bullet's direction changes, which is not supposed to be happening since it should only go towards the center

Comment: why would you rotate the bullet spawn? or dont child bullets to the spawner

Comment: video of it not working: https://dev-slugarius.pantheonsite.io/video/. I haven't rotated the spawn or anything

Comment: then i would suggest some debugging. pershot make it move different coloured balls to the locations of worldcenter (as i dont think thats where you think), and spawn bullets and not give them movement, so you can check what they spawn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using

```
Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenCenter);
```

screenCenter.x and screenCenter.y are converted to Ray based on camera position and rotation, while screenCenter.z is Distance from Camera/Position on Ray. So basically if your screenCenter.z == 0 the function will always return camera position. Try putting your cords to x, y and setting z to 200 so the function will return point on the center of screen at distance 200 from camera.